# How to add datasource to the local rdlc report dynamically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, desktop-application

I am new to to windows desktop application development.

I have one form containing the report viewer control. One .rdlc file that contains the design of the report.

My problem is that I want to bind the datasource for the report dynamically.

My **Code** :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication3{

    public partial class Form1 : Form{ 

        OleDbConnection cn;
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        OleDbDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;

        public Form1(){
            InitializeComponent();
        } 

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
            cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\Bill\\dbBill.accdb");
            string query = "Select * from BillMaster where BillNo=1";
            cn.Open();
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, cn);
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);            
            cn.Close();         
        }   
    } 
 }
```

I want to bind the `ds` to my report.

Report file also contains the table and some text boxes that display the data.

How to do so.? and how to bind the data to the text box residing in `.rdlc` file? I have searched a lot but found the solutions of ASP.net only.

How to I achieve this in desktop application.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/473844/Using-Custom-Data-Source-to-create-RDLC-Reports):

```
void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(
    object sender,
    Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    // get empID from the parameters
    int iEmpID = Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameters[0].Values[0]);

    // remove all previously attached Datasources, since we want to attach a
    // new one
    e.DataSources.Clear();

    // Retrieve employeeFamily list based on EmpID
    var employeeFamily = CpReportCustomData.Data.CustomDS.GetAllEmployeeFamily()
                         .FindAll(element => element.ID == iEmpID);

    // add retrieved dataset or you can call it list to data source
    e.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource()
    {
        Name = "DSEmployeeFamily",
        Value = employeeFamily

    });
}
```